# Unable to increment hour in JavaScript Date() object and get expected Object output

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get two **datetime** object, where the second one is one hour greater than the first one:

```
Sat Jan 30 2021 01:56:53 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)  
Sat Jan 30 2021 02:56:53 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
```

My code looks like this:

```
minStartDate = new Date();  
minEndDate = new Date();  
ngOnInit() {  
    console.log(this.minStartDate);  
    console.log(this.minEndDate);  
    console.log(this.minEndDate.setHours(this.minEndDate.getHours() + 1));  
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Sat Jan 30 2021 01:56:53 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
Sat Jan 30 2021 01:56:53 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
1611964613955
```

Comment: Don't do date arithmetic yourself, because there are too many quirks due to timezones, calendar changes, and historical artifacts for you to write code that actually works (at best, it doesn't work, but far worse is when it _seems_ to work). Use a proper, exhaustively tested datetime library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) instead.

Comment: you are logging the result of setHours which is that number underneath, instead of logging the actual date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @Mike suggested on comments, Using **moment.js** solved the problem for me.
The final code is:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';  
minStartDate = new Date();  
minEndDate = new Date();  
ngOnInit() {  
    console.log(this.minStartDate);  
    console.log(this.minEndDate);  
    console.log(moment(this.minEndDate).add(1, 'hours').toDate()); //expected output
}
```

The output:

```
Sat Jan 30 2021 02:30:08 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)  
Sat Jan 30 2021 02:30:08 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)  
Sat Jan 30 2021 03:30:08 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)
```

Comment: moment is not the recommended way to go btw, you should choose a different library like dayjs while you still can

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But could you please explain why? Because @Mike suggested moment.js on comments above

Comment: They literally say it themselves: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ . The biggest issue being that moment objects are mutable, and the large package size.